# Recommended reading about antennas?

Tags: resource-recommendations, radio, antennas

I am trying to learn a bit about [antenna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_%28radio%29) theory in order to understand how Nikola Tesla may have misunderstood them. (Thank you CuriousOne for your response to my earlier question! It was helpful in the best way in that it led to more questions.) Does anyone have any recommendations for particularly good books, blog posts, articles, websites, etc.?

Comment: Did you search for "antenna theory"? There are plenty of resources online. At the end of the day, of course, you will have to confront numerical solutions for Maxwell's equations, if you want to understand the design of non-trivial antennas, but that's really an engineering discipline. Physics teaching in this area rarely goes beyond the near-field and far-field solution of simple dipoles.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really go past anything written by R. E. Colins on the subject of antenna theory.

[Robert E. Collin, "Antennas and Radiowave Propagation"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070118086)

This book with give you a thorough discussion in the theoretical grounding of such useful intuitive crutches such as the effective area formula, gain versus directivity formula and, above all, electromagnetic reciprocity and its equivalent the Lorentz Lemma. The book also goes into detailed scattering theory and the scattering matrices for loads and terminations.

A related topic, that also helps antenna intuition, is the [Optical Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_theorem).

But as CuriousOne says in his comment, antenna behavior is fiendishly complex owing to the feedback in the phenomenon: launched / received waves beget reaction currents in the antenna further to the drive voltage, and these alter the electromagnetic field. Many antenna problems can be solved numerically as [fixed point problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) when the solution electromagnetic field is thought of as a fixed point of the linear operator (a convolution) modelling the mapping of the incident to total field. Beyond these vague comments, the theoretical understanding of any antenna system that one can easily get is needfully limited and must be complemented by the results of numerical simulations. If you want "big picture" theoretical insights into antennas, in my opinion your most fruitful avenue of learning would be to study the reciprocity theorem (Lorentz lemma) thoroughly and understand its derivation fully, then to apply its thinking to the problem at hand.

Comment: Excellent description of the problem! Can I suggest that another useful tool to understand antennas is a vector impedance analyzer? I never had much fun with antennas unless I had one of those in the lab and they are really extremely handy to get a "hands-on" feeling for what is happening in reality.